# How to get response from Login Api for Login Layout page?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I parse a json feed from a Api and it contains some feeds,in my login page i need to enter two fields from the feed and i need to get a response whether the feed is correct.. if not i need to register .. how i will save the login details from my feed and how to get the response from the feed

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Do you have a problem parsing api responses into JSON Objects?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the values from response?

Comment: i parse all the feeds .. my problem is that i need to save the email id and password in shared preferences, and want to check if it is right when the user enters.. if not it shoould show a error mesage ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private void getJSON()
{
/* [...] code inside the function that receives the response */ 
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        String status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
        if(status.compareTo("success") != 0)
            throw new JSONException(status);
        if(!checkEmailPassword( jResponse.getString("email"), jResponse.getString("password") ))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bad response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

private boolean checkEmailPassword(String email, String password)
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean verified =  false;
    if( preferences.getString("email", "").compareTo(email) == 0
     && preferences.getString("password", "").compareTo(password) == 0 )
    {
        verified = true;
    }
    return verified;
}
```